# How to capture multiple occurrence using capturing parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract only the key string part "**ProcessName**" and "**ProcessID**" from the text.
text could have more key. (I'm just using the text with two keys for simplicity)
Is it possible to capture multiple occurrence of the group?

```
var text = "[ProcessName] - [ProcessID]";
var regex = new RegExp(/\[[(A-Za-z0-9)]+\]/g);
var result = regex.exec(text);
console.log(result);
```

When I use exec, it gives me just one match and with the bracket so it has no use it seems.
[image]

Also tried match() but it contains square brackets. Tried many times but cannot seem to get it right.

```
var result = text.match(regex);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know what your pattern matches? `\[[(A-Za-z0-9)]+\]` matches a `[` followed with 1 or more `(`, letters, digits, `)`, and then matches a trailing `]`. There is no capturing group here. What do you really want to match? An alphanumeric inside `[...]`? Use `/\[([a-z0-9]+)]/ig` with `RegExp#exec` in a loop. Access match[1] value.

Comment: It's probably best if you can run `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` and include the resulting text, rather than posting images of the results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mispositioned the round and square brackets, thus making a capture group part of the character class preventing the submatch to be created.

You need to swap the positions of the brackets:

```
/\[([a-z0-9]+)]/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG9sP8/1) and a JS demo below.

**Pattern details**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `([a-z0-9]+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more alphanumerics
- `]`  - a literal closing bracket (no need escaping it when it is outside a character class)
- `/gi` - global and case insensitive matching modifiers (`[a-z]` will also match `A-Z`, processing each non-overlapping match)

```js
var re = /\[([a-z0-9]+)]/gi; 
var str = '[ProcessName] - [ProcessID]';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

In the code, we need to use `RegExp#exec` rather than `String#match` because the latter, when used with a regex having a global modifier, will discard all submatches (captured parts) (see [*Description* at MDN `String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) page).

Comment: Note that `RegExp#exec` and the `/\[([a-z0-9]+)]/gi` regex go hand in hand here, if you need to use a regex without a global flag (to only match one occurrence), just use `String#match` then.

Answer (score 1):

Soon after I pose a question, i found the answer...

```
var regex = new RegExp(/\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]/g);
var matches, output = [];
while (matches = regex.exec(text))
{
    output.push(matches[1]);
}
```